# React and CSS: Having issues with CSS style Within React App

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In the code below, when there are new notifications, the bell icon turns red. The issue I am having is when I click on the bell icon the notification menu drops down successfully but the color of the bell goes back to its default greyish color. I want the red color to remain if the bell icon is clicked and the notification menu drops down.

```
class TopNavbar extends Component{
    state = {
      notificationsAlert: 'red'
  }
  static propTypes = {
    newNotifications: PropTypes.object,
    viewNotifications: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

   toggleNotificationMenu = () =>{
    const {newNotifications} = this.props.notifications;
    const notificationMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("NotificationsMainContainer");
    const notificationIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("TopNavbarNotificationIcon");


    if(newNotifications.length > 0){
      this.props.viewNotifications()
    }

    if(notificationMenu[0].style.display === "block"){
      notificationMenu[0].style.display = "none"
      notificationIcon[0].style.color = null
    }
    else{
      notificationMenu[0].style.display = "block"
      notificationIcon[0].style.color = "red"
    }

  }

    render(){
        const {newNotifications} = this.props.notifications;
        const style = {
            color: this.state.notificationsAlert
      }

      return(
          <div className="TopNavbar">
            <div className="NavbarLastSection">
            <span className="TopNavbarNotification" onClick={this.toggleNotificationMenu}>
            {newNotifications.length === 0 
            ? <i className="TopNavbarNotificationIcon"><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon="bell"/></a></i>
            : <i className="TopNavbarNotificationIcon" style={style}><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon="bell"/> 
              </a></i>}
            </span>
            </div>
          </div>
      )
    }
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notifications: state.notifications,
  error: state.error
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  viewNotifications
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(TopNavbar);
```

Comment: I think that way `document.getElementsByClassName("NotificationsMainContainer")` not good with react, u should take look at refs in react. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: That class is in another file. That file only focuses on the notification dropdown menu. It works successfully. I am only having issue with the color of the bell icon

Comment: That happened after changing `state` reset all of your styles.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Thank you

Comment: Make a project on codesandbox or somewhere ill help you, I think for helping you I have to check another component, I need more information. also, I prefer to use Material-Ui for making something like this.